# Redis Stuck on Get

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, redis

I dockerized my Node + Express + Postgres + Redis app.

It seems to work well, it is able to write in the database and to the redis cache. I am encountering issues though with the retrieval on redis cache.

It gets stuck in client.get (client is redis):

```js
await client.get(collarId, (err, data) => {
}
```

I checked the persistency of redis, I was able to find dump.rdb and the new record can be seen there.

Here is my docker-compose for redis:

```js
cache:
    container_name: cache
    image: 'redis:latest'
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    expose:
      - 6379
    command: redis-server --save 20 1 --loglevel warning --requirepass redis --appendonly yes
    volumes:
      - ./redis-vol:/data
    networks:
      - my-network
```

Any ways I can check why it is stuck on `client.get`? it works fine outside of the container.

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the client code running?  How are you connecting to Redis?  Do you have log messages or other output that suggests the client is making an initial connection successfully?  Do you both need `await` (usually used with methods that return promises) and a callback function in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was able to get it to work!

Apparently the client must be created with `legacyMode: true`.

```js
const redis = require('redis')

redis.createClient({
  url: process.env.REDIS_URL,
  legacyMode: true
})
```

Comment: How in the world is that the solution?????? YOU'RE A HERO KZAIWO!

Comment: @Squareoot Really glad to know this helped you! Cheers!